# Generating a formatted data array form a json request

Tags: php, arrays, json

can someone offer me some pointers as to how id go about formatting my JSON response in the correct array to use with charts.js.

I have a custom api getting data from our CRM, the api returns the following JSON array

```json
"printers": [
    {
        "s_month": "2020-03",
        "class_name": "Magicard 300",
        "a_count": 7,
        "s_count": 7
    },
    {
        "s_month": "2020-03",
        "class_name": "Magicard 600",
        "a_count": 1,
        "s_count": 1
    },
    {
        "s_month": "2020-03",
        "class_name": "Rio Pro 360",
        "a_count": 7,
        "s_count": 7
    },
    {
        "s_month": "2020-04",
        "class_name": "Magicard 300",
        "a_count": 2,
        "s_count": 2
    },
    {
        "s_month": "2020-04",
        "class_name": "Magicard 600",
        "a_count": 11,
        "s_count": 11
    },
    {
        "s_month": "2020-04",
        "class_name": "Pronto",
        "a_count": 1,
        "s_count": 1
    },
    {
        "s_month": "2020-05",
        "class_name": "Magicard 600",
        "a_count": 27,
        "s_count": 27
    }
]
```

Im trying to loop through this array to create the following array to then use in charts.js

```
labels: ['2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-05'],
datasets: [
    {
        label: 'Pronto',
        data: [0, 1, 0],
    },
    {
        label: 'Magicard 300',
        data: [7, 2, 0],
    },
    {
        label: 'Magicard 600',
        data: [1, 11, 27],
    },
    {
        label: 'Rio Pro 360',
        data: [7, 0, 0],
    }
]
```

I've tried the php below to loop through the JSON array and format it but wandered if anyone had advice how to do this better

```php
$months     = array();
$classes    = array();
$dataset    = array();

foreach ($printers as $printer) {
    $months[]       = $printer['s_month'];
    $classes[]      = $printer['class_name'];
}
$data['months']     = array_unique($months);
$data['class']      = array_unique($classes);

foreach ($data['class'] as $class) {
    $dataset[$count] = array('label' => $data['class']);
    foreach ($printers as $printer) {
        if ($printer['class_name'] == $data['class']) {
            $dataset[$count]['data'] = $printer['a_count'];
        } else {
            $dataset[$count]['data'][] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone offer suggestions on mapping this data to the required format

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array indexed on the class and the date. Then you can access to the data easily.

```
$dataset = [];
$by_class = [];
foreach ($printers as $printer)
{
    $class = $printer['class_name'];
    $a_count = $printer['a_count'];
    $month = $printer['s_month'];
    
    if (empty($dataset['labels']) || !in_array($month, $dataset['labels'])) 
        $dataset['labels'][] = $month;
    $dataset['datasets'][$class]['label'] = $class;
    
    $by_class[$class][$month] = $a_count;
}

foreach ($dataset['datasets'] as $class => $unused) {
    foreach ($dataset['labels'] as $idx => $month) {
        if (isset($by_class[$class][$month])) {
            $dataset['datasets'][$class]['data'][$idx] = $by_class[$class][$month];
        }
        else {
            $dataset['datasets'][$class]['data'][] = 0;
        }
    }
    
}

echo json_encode($dataset, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs: ([demo](https://3v4l.org/PJKuH))

```
{
    "labels": [
        "2020-03",
        "2020-04",
        "2020-05"
    ],
    "datasets": {
        "Magicard 300": {
            "label": "Magicard 300",
            "data": [
                7,
                2,
                0
            ]
        },
        "Magicard 600": {
            "label": "Magicard 600",
            "data": [
                1,
                11,
                27
            ]
        },
        "Rio Pro 360": {
            "label": "Rio Pro 360",
            "data": [
                7,
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        "Pronto": {
            "label": "Pronto",
            "data": [
                0,
                1,
                0
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Syscall so i didn't nee to use array_unique to get the unique fields

Comment: It's done by `!in_array($month, $dataset['labels'])`.
And, by override values, here : `$dataset['datasets'][$class]['label'] = $class`.